# Is it correct query for PHP?

Tags: php, mariadb

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `posts` (title, author, body, tags)
                VALUES (`$title`, `$author`, `$body`, `$tags`)
                (SELECT * FROM category WHERE name = $category)";
```

posts and category both are different tables?

Comment: Short answer, no.. For starters, your php variables `$title`, etc should be in inverted commas

Comment: `queries` depends on backend database, not PHP

Comment: $q = "INSERT INTO `posts` (title, author, body, tags)
                    VALUES (`$title`, `$author`, `$body`, `$tags`)
                    (SELECT * FROM category WHERE name = $category)"; Still showing syntax exception @gaganshera

Comment: `INSERT INTO posts (title, author, body, tags) VALUES ('$title', '$author', '$body', '$tags')`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables with the values:

```
$etitle = somehow_escape($title); ...
INSERT INTO posts
          (title, author, body, tags)
          VALUES
          ('$etitle', '$eauthor', '$ebody', '$etags');
```

If fetching the values from another table:

```
INSERT INTO posts
          (title, author, body, tags)
    SELECT title, author, body, tags
        FROM category
        WHERE ...
```

- You *must* escape the values -- Think about what would happen if a `'` were in the $title!
- When using `SELECT` with `INSERT`, there is no `VALUES` cause.
- No need for the parens around the `SELECT` subquery (in this situation).